# In Kotlin, why does char.toInt() return the number + 48?

Tags: kotlin, char

I was making some code to put my tiles into a mutableMap of the tiles and their coords based on their tags I manually put in, and I found that `char.toString().toInt()` returns the character as a number like expected, but for some reason, `char.toInt()` returns it as a number + 48. Why does it do this? Here's my code that shows this:

```
    board.forEach { tile: View ->
        var x: Int? = null
        var y: Int? = null
        tile.tag.toString().toCharArray().forEach { c: Char ->
            if(c.isDigit() && x == null) x = c.toInt() else if(c.toString() != "," && y == null) y = c.toString().toInt()
        }
        tileMap[Coord(x!!, y!!)] = tile
    }
```

I have some code that prints the tile's tag (which is what is used to determine the Coords for the tileMap) and the tile's Coords' x & y values (from the tileMap) whenever you tap on them. So for example, when I tap on a tile 1 to the right of the bottom left corner, I expect to see "1,0 | (X: 1, Y: 0)" but instead (when both x and y are defined by `char.toInt()`) I get "1,0 | (X: 49, Y: 48)"

A tile at Coords x=1, y=2 (tag = "1,2") when put into the tileMap would have its coords in the map input like this:
| tileMap X definition | tileMap Y definition | Coords from tileMap | Actual Coords(from its tag) |
|:----:|:------:|:------:|:-----:|
| `char.toInt()`  |  `char.toInt()`  | `"49, 50"` | `"1, 2"` |
| `char.toString().toInt()` | `char.toString().toInt()` | `"1, 2"` | `"1, 2"` |
| `char.toInt()` | `char.toString().toInt()` | `"49, 2"` | `"1, 2"` |
Why does `char.toInt()` (and `char.code`) return 48 more than the number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because computers generally process numbers, each character is internally represented as a number. When using ASCII character encoding, each character is a number in 0-127 range. Unicode is more complicated, but let's stick to ASCII for simplicity.

If we look into the [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters), we can see that for example the letter `A` is internally stored as a decimal value `65`. Digit `0` is stored as `48`, digit `1` as `49` and so on.

`char.toInt()` doesn't mean: "interpret this character as a digit and return it as integer". It means: "return an internal numeric value for this character". And as we can see in the ASCII table, internal representation of `0` is `48`.

Comment: Also Unicode *is* more complicated, but *UTF-8* (which you probably use a lot) is ASCII-compatible, meaning it uses the same codes ASCII does. So this works the same for UTF-8 too, in case you were wondering! `String.toInt()` doesn't care about any of this - it's purely about parsing actual digits, which is why the conversion works how you expect